# revert rows to default column value mysql

Tags: mysql, default

I am using MySQL community server 5.1.  Is there a way to just set all the rows back to their default column values with one query?

I just added a lot of rows. I had default values for most of the columns specified, but for some reason all the columns values were set = 0 instead. I was wondering if there is a query to set all the column values to their default value, and I would need the ability for a `where` clause too.

something like this for example:

```
update table set values = values(default) where id > 300;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why you would ever want to do this is beyond me.  What is the point in having records with only default data?

Comment: that is for me to worry about ;-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a DEFAULT keyword available in INSERT and UPDATE queries which you can use in place of any real column value:

```
update my_table set my_column = DEFAULT where id > 300;
```

As documented [in the MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html)

Note that there is also a [DEFAULT() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_default), as mentioned in a previous answer; with which you can select any column's default value for use.

Comment: should have known, even though i have been to that docs page a zillion times :-/ thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You should try:

```
UPDATE table_name SET col = DEFAULT(col) WHERE id > 300;
```