# set null value to a not null column (`disc_base_pct` decimal(7,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1.0000' ), but did not get the default value

Tags: mysql

I have a column disc_base_pct in one table where I try to avoid NULL. However, the records of this table are from another table where they may use null if the discount is not applicable for them. The data is inserted from another table in this way:

```
insert into sandbox_1.table (id, conditions, base price, disc_base_pct)
select id, conditions, base price, disc_base_pct from user_1.table;
```

I assume the column will be set to the default value if the current value is not possible. And 0 value has some real meaning so 0 cannot be used. Finally, I set the column disc_base_pct to NOT NULL default -1 like below

```
 `disc_base_pct` decimal(7,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1.0000',
```

I hope in this way MySQL can automatically convert NULL to default value -1.
But when I test it, it does not work as I assume.

First, let us set that the disc_base_pct value is set to 0.5. The disc_base_pct column type is set to (decimal(7,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1.0000')
Then I run the query below,

```
update sandbox_1.table
set disc_base_pct = null;
```

I will get a warning as

```
1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1048 Column 'disc_base_pct' cannot be null Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1
```

After that, I run select disc_base_pct from temp_tbl_fc_fare_map; The result value show that the disc_base_pct is set to 0 rather than the default value -1.
[Please see the result figure by click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dion.png)

By the way, @FaNo_FN mentioned that I should receive an error rather than a warning when I update a NULL value to a NOT NULL column. But I just get a warning message. Does it involve any MySQL configuration？

Is there any way to force the NOT NULL column to be set to the default value when the input value is NULL?

I got a solution as [revert rows to default column value mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614722/revert-rows-to-default-column-value-mysql).
It will not help in my scenario because if 0 is possible value from the source tables. If the table already convert the NULL to 0, I will not be able to identify the 0 is the original value or the 0 is the value converted from the NULL. It makes big difference. The 0 from NULL means there is no discount allowed, while the original 0 may indicate it is a special event of free product.

But the answer will indicate the modification in the input section. It will work. But I still wonder why the default value does not work.

```
insert into sandbox_1.table (id, conditions, base price, disc_base_pct)
select id, conditions, base price, if（disc_base_pct is null, -1, disc_base_pct) from user_1.table;
```

Latest Update:
@FaNo_FN thanks for FaNo_FN, it looks like the result may vary according to the MySQL version.
In my local MySQL 8.0.13, it matches my description in this question.
However, for MySQL 8.0.23 as the link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=05ca7b6c570080896d6d3136cc74dc5b , it will refuse to set value to NULL

Comment: When you said "others", are you referring to users? But regardless, what is the method of "others" to insert value? Through a web app? Or run query directly?

Comment: Would you be able to show the output of your statement? 'SET disc_base_pct = null;' is not the correct statement syntax. Unless you mean 'UPDATE `test` SET disc_base_pct = null;'. When I do that MySQL tells me that disc column 'cannot be null' which sounds like it's working fine for me. I'm not quite sure how it's letting you input anything with that command, unless you're using some older version of mysql.

Comment: @SenorCardgage 
Hi. Thanks for reply. When I use the syntax: ``` update sandbox_1.table set disc_base_pct = null ; ``` It also shows me disc column 'cannot be null' . However, when I select it after update: ``` select disc_base_pct from sandbox_1.table ``` it still shows 0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [revert rows to default column value mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614722/revert-rows-to-default-column-value-mysql)

Comment: It can be an alternative solution. What I hope is that the MySQL table can automatically do the conversion for me as I set the default value and disable the NULL. If the table already converts NULL to 0, then I cannot identify which 0 is the original value and which 0 is converted from NULL. @stickybit

Comment: You might check out the coalesce function. :)

Comment: Your "does not work" is still not clear. [The testing here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1962ebfd45dc63d4ee3a226bf86940f5) show it will work. As in if the value is `null`, you'll receive error message - is that what you meant "it won't work?". Both `INSERT` and `UPDATE` will return the error message. Then you said after the `UPDATE`, the value is still `0`. Means that the populated value is already there and since the `UPDATE` query return error, it won't update the original table to your default value.

Comment: @FaNo_FN Hi. I think there is some difference between the running result.
Let us assume the value disc_base_pct  is 0.5 first. The column type is decimal(7,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1.0000'.
I run 
update temp_tbl_fc_fare_map
set disc_base_pct = null
 ;
Then I run select disc_base_pct from temp_tbl_fc_fare_map;
I will see the value become 0 rather than -1

Comment: When I run 
update temp_tbl_fc_fare_map
set disc_base_pct = null
 ;
It will just give me a warning like : 1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1048 Column 'disc_base_pct' cannot be null Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1
It does not give me any error. @FaNo_FN

Comment: Please look at this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=19af499c72f1949d23a5d84693f59f24 . I assume it's close to your attempt however I cannot replicate the situation. By the way, the `warning` and `error` are quite confusing. You can see in the fiddle where I wrote `show warnings;` it returns `level` as `Error` so I think `warning = error`? .. in MySQL?

Comment: The purpose of the default value is to set it when other fields in that row are set and the dict_base_pct wasn't.  Ex. if you ran your query above, but without the disc_base_pct column, or it's value, the column would be populated with the default. So: insert into sandbox_1.table (id, conditions, base price)
select id, conditions, base price from user_1.table;

Comment: @FaNo_FN Thanks for providing this powerful tool. I guess it is some back-end logic difference. My local version is 8.0.13 and your tool's version is 8.0.23.
I try this program in your tool, it gets your result:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=05ca7b6c570080896d6d3136cc74dc5b
But if I run it in local, it still returns 0. If you are interested, you may want to try in your local and see. the program is below

Comment: @FaNo_FN
{
select version();
drop table test;
create table test(id int, val decimal(7,4) not null default -1);
show create table test;
insert into test(id, val) values(1, 0.5);
select * from test;

update test
set val = NULL;
select * from test;
}

Comment: @DoyleB Hi, you are right. If you omit it, then it works fine. like 
insert into test(id) values(1);
If I run the query above, it will populate the default value in disc_base_pct field.
If I set disc_base_pct = NULL, it will give me 0. If you can write it down as an answer, we may close the question.
By the way it also looks like a version issue, my local 8.0.13 will convert NULL to 0 but the 8.0.23 from the website will reject the NULL :P https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=05ca7b6c570080896d6d3136cc74dc5b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the default value is to set it when other fields in that row are set and the dict_base_pct wasn't. If you ran your query above, but without the disc_base_pct column, or it's value, the column would be populated with the default. Ex:

```
insert into sandbox_1.table (id, conditions, base price) 
select id, conditions, base price from user_1.table;
```

And, yes, depending on how sql_mode is set you will get either a warning or an error when trying to insert an invalid value.  If you are inserting from a select statement you might also look into one of the following functions:

- if (like you showed in your question)
- case
- ifnull
- coalesce